# Why does Mac OS X come with ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

Why does Mac OS X come with ruby and ruby on rails pre-installed? Does the OS actually use it at all? Can I update my Ruby, Rails or Gem versions safely without something spitting the dummy?

Comment: It also comes with python installed.

Comment: You can update those things, but, because there are no regression or integration tests, you have no way of knowing whether you screwed up something that the system relies on. Try my command listed in the comment below your selected answer and you'll see Apple relies on the languages; They're not there for our pleasure solely. @Ned Deily recommends being careful and suggests alternative ways of dealing with it. I'll also recommend using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) for the chore.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As others have noted, OS X comes with various open source packages pre-installed.  While this can be a nice convenience, the packages often are only updated to new versions as part of a major OS X release (like 10.5 to 10.6).  Also, some packages are used elsewhere by other parts of OS X and there is no easy way to know which.  In general, Apple assumes (and you should, too) that everything under `/System/Library` and `/usr/`, except for `/usr/local/`, is part of OS X and is administered by Apple.  You should not attempt to remove or modify files in those hierarchies.  That includes just about all of the open source packages, including `Ruby`.

Instead, to *upgrade* an existing package, the right approach is to install a new version in a separate location (say, `/usr/local/`) and invoke the new version by an absolute path reference (`/usr/local/bin/ruby`) or manipulating the shell `PATH` environment variable, if necessary.  `/usr/local/` is often used if installing directly from source.  Many people prefer to use one of the 3rd-party open source package distributors, such as [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), [Fink](https://www.finkproject.org/), or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), each of which has its own package manager and installation locations.

Answer (score 7):

No the OS does not use, it is just that Apple wants to make her products a bit more appealing to developers. (there is also Python preinstalled along with some other packets).

You can safely update your Ruby, Rails, Gems but the default Ruby version is a bit outdated. Check RVM so that you can install different Rubies in your system

Comment: How do you know that Apple doesn't use Ruby, Python, Perl or TCL? According to my checks there is system use of all four languages: Try `locate *.py | grep ^/usr | grep -v /System` with their standard extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [Rubystack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) if you want to play with more up-to-date environments without interfering with the existing versions. Disclaimer, I am one of the developers of RubyStack. It is freely available under the open source Apache 2.0 License.

Comment: You should disclose your affiliation with the company each time you mention your product. Otherwise, it is considered as spam here.

Comment: I have done so in most other questions and is clearly specified in my profile as well. BitNami is not a company, and we do not make any money with the stacks (though it is sponsored by one and we provide support and services to some other open source companies such as Sugar, Alfresco, etc.). In any case, I have now updated my response. Also, I believe there was no need to downvote the answer as it is directly related to the topic.

Comment: I did not downvote. The spam flag works like that. It will go away after a while now that you updated your answer. Note however that you really should specify your affiliation in each of your answers, it is not enough to have it on your profile, so you should check that all your answers recommending your products include a disclaimer